# core image filter slider not working smoothly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, core-image

i am using core images when i applied different filters it works fine but when i change values using uislider ,slider didnt work smoothly i tried different approaches but no result like i use this filter

```
  filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIStraightenFilter"];
    [filter setValue:beginImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
```

and when i change slider value i use this code ,it works fine and apply change image but problem is that slider not working smoothly

```
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:slideValue]  forKey:@"inputAngle"];
```

Comment: try using like this slideValue += .50f;

Comment: i tried but it didnt work and also it changes my slider value with addition of .5

Comment: Can you please show your code to change the slider Value

Comment: this the code [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:slideValue]  forKey:@"inputAngle"];

Comment: - (IBAction)sliderAction:(id)sender {
    
    UISlider *mySlider = (UISlider *) sender;
 float progressAsInt =(float)(mySlider.value + 0.2f);
    [filterTemp setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progressAsInt]  forKey: @"inputAngle"];
    CIImage *resultImage = [filterTemp valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    self.modified.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:resultImage fromRect:resultImage.extent]];
}
i use like this and its working fine for me

Comment: i think that is a simulator issue., try it in device